# In case of same card in both player

Tags: poker

Suppose two players in a game of poker (assume Texas Hold'em) have cards with the same values. For example, Player A and Player B have the cards 4 & 9.
The board shows a 2,3,4,7, and 8 face up.

Who would be the winner, Player A or Player B?

Comment: This question is already answered on [Poker Stack Exchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com/a/4405/3340).

Comment: It is also already answered here.

Comment: ... But to avoid sending people who found this question around to others, the short answer is that the two players tie and split the pot down the middle (any indivisible fraction remaining in the pot for the next hand).

Comment: That is incorrect.  The remaining dollar (or fraction of a dollar, if you're playing microstakes) is awarded to the player in worst position.